# Redirect http to https is not working

Tags: maven

I want to redirect Http to Https.  So for that I created a certificate using 'keytool -genkey -alias mydomain -keyalg RSA -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password' this command.

### pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>${webappDirectory}</warSourceDirectory>
                <path>bigdata</path>
                <stopPort>9966</stopPort>
                <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
                <httpsPort>8443</httpsPort>
                <keystoreFile>/usr/local/Keystorefiles/keystore.jks</keystoreFile>
                <keystorePass>arya123</keystorePass>
                <password>arya123</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

### web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
<web-resource-name>securedapp</web-resource-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</web-resource-collection>
<user-data-constraint>
<transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

### Server.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server address="localhost" port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <GlobalNamingResources>
      <Resource auth="Container" description="User database  that        can    be  updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"  name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml"  type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
   <Connector address="dt" connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080"  protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
      <!-- <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />-->
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/usr/local/Keystorefiles/keystore.jks"
           keystorePass="arya123" />

 <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
 <Engine defaultHost="dt" name="Catalina">
 <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm>
 <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="dt" unpackWARs="true">
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>

  <Context docBase="HelloWeb" path="/HelloWeb" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:HelloWeb"/><Context docBase="SpringMVCExample" path="/SpringMVCExample" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVCExample"/><Context docBase="TrialApp" path="/TrialApp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TrialApp"/><Context docBase="ABDFver3" path="/bigdata" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ABDFver3"/></Host>
</Engine>
</Service>
 </Server>
```

This much I did. But when I  gave URL it doesn't redirect to Https. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to manually do the '*redirect-thing*'. Normally this is done by the server for you - and that's the reason why you don't just have to edit settings within your application but also on your server!

One of many tutorials for Tomcat can be found here: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl

Comment: I edit my server also.                                                                    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
               keystoreFile="/usr/local/keystorefiles/keystore.jks"
               keystorePass="arya123" />     ... Yet its not working

Comment: Can you specify in detail *what is not working*? What is the behaviour, wenn you type in **https://<domain>:8443** - is it working? So maybe only the redirect from http port is not working?

Comment: When I type the URL it says 'Could not connect to localhost:8443'.

Comment: Can you post the complete server.xml?